# How to include urlencode to source?

Tags: php, html, css

i'm trying to use

> http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php

But i don't know how to include to my source. I need to encode the URL to use

> file_get_contents

My code :

```
     <script class="ccscript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <title>GET URL IMAGE</title>
    <div style="width:1265px;margin:auto;">
    <?php

    if(isset($_POST['ok'])){
        $link = $_POST['link'];
        $source = file_get_contents($link);
        if(strpos($source,'example.org')!==false){
            $pa = '#"\s><a\shref=\"(.*?)\".*?>#s';
        }else{
            $pa = '#<img\sclass.*?src=\"(.*?)\"\/>#s';
        }
        preg_match_all($pa, $source, $matches);
        echo '<div style="float:right"><textarea class="text" cols="110" rows="50">';

        foreach($matches[1] as $item) //GET URL 1,IMG TAG = 0
        {
            if(strpos($item,'http://')!==false)
            {
                echo $item."\r\n";
            }
        }
        echo '</textarea></div>';
    }
    ?>
    <div style="float:left;width:210px;margin-right:15px">
<form action="get.php" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="link" size="60" />
    <input type="submit" name="ok" />
</form>
```

Example URL : `http://www.example.org/%E5%9F/`

When i try to get the image url,i get this

> failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable

I think i need to use urlencode so i can get the image url

Comment: What would be the correct url instead of `http://www.example.org/%E5%9F/`?

Comment: like i said,i need to use "file_get_contents" if i don't encode the url,i can't get the contents of the URL !

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$source = file_get_contents(urlencode($link));
```

Comment: the URL i'm trying to use file_get_contents is using cloudflare ddos protection,i think that's why i can't get the image url !

Comment: Please edit your answer to include some explanation. Code-only answers do very little to educate future SO readers. Your answer is in the moderation queue for being low-quality.